# Passing a checkbox control to a function

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

I am using Access 365 and VisualBasic.  I have a number of checkboxes on a form that I want to display just a subset of these at a time, so I want to reposition the top of the checkboxes so that no matter which are currently displayed, I can make them line up nicely.

So, I have declared an array of checkboxes that I want to dynamically add those checkboxes to display:

```
' Array holding the checkboxes that will be displayed, depending upon species, sex, etc.
Dim arrCheckBoxes(cNumCheckboxes) As CheckBox
```

Then as I determine that a specific check box should be shown, I want to add it to the array at the next available position using this function (which will also update the next available position):

```
Private Sub AddCheckbox(ByRef arrCheckBoxes() As CheckBox, ByRef chkNew As CheckBox, ByRef intCurrentCheckbox)
    intCurrentCheckbox = intCurrentCheckbox + 1
    arrCheckBoxes(intCurrentCheckbox) = chkNew
End Sub
```

My problem is that in the code that calls the AddCheckbox function, I cannot figure out how to pass the check box.  I am using the following code (CatNeuter is the checkbox from my form).

```
Call AddCheckbox(arrCheckBoxes, Me.CatNeuter, intCurrentCheckbox)
```

However, Me.CatNeuter is always 0, so I think I am getting just the value, and not the checkbox control itself.  I've tried numerous different methods such as:

```
Me.Controls!CatNeuter
Me.Controls("CatNeuter")
```

But I just cannot figure out how to pass the actual checkbox so I can then go through the array and change the Top property for each checkbox.

Regards,
Lise

Comment: `Set arrCheckBoxes(intCurrentCheckbox) = chkNew`

Comment: Thanks, but chkNew is still 0 when it goes to the AddCheckbox function.

Comment: Add this as the first line in `AddCheckbox` - `Debug.Print chkNew.Name, Typename(chkNew)` and see what the output is.

Comment: Cool - it is a checkbox!  I just got confused because I hovered over it and it was always 0.  Thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out how to accept your solution!

Comment: Added as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set` for objects:

```
Set arrCheckBoxes(intCurrentCheckbox) = chkNew
```